# Insert single quotes around a specific columns data with SQL Select Query (or python)

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I'm creating a drop down menu in Flask which is populated with staff names from a postgres table. I'm also using the primary key in addition to the names  because with the framework I'm using, the data needs to be in a tuple like so:

staff_choices=[("", ""), ('1', 'John Jacobs'), ('2', 'Joe Pape'), ('3', 'Lyn Lino')]

However when I run my select query:

```
SELECT * FROM radio_playlist.staff
```

The output produced looks like this *** note the integer values- they don't have quotes around them:

```
[[1, 'John Jacobs'], [2, 'Joe Pape'], [3, 'Lyn Lino']]
```

This is causing issues when I create the drop-down so I need to somehow automatically add quotes around the integer values.I have very little experience with SQL- is this possible and if so how? I'm also open to doing this in python after the output has been saved in a function if this makes more sense.

EDIT*** I'm currently running this command to produce the output using psycopg2 fucntions:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM radio_playlist.staff")
data =  cur.fetchall()
```

Using the above psycopg2 method data contains the output:

[[1, 'John Jacobs'], [2, 'Joe Pape'], [3, 'Lyn Lino']]

Comment: Why not convert them to str type in python? I think you can do something like `[(str(x), y) for x, y in cur.fetchall()]`

Comment: I'm new to python also but I will google your suggestion now and see if I can work it out. Thanks.

Comment: @Psidom - You nailed it :)